# django IntegrityError for create object

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have this models . When i use One To One relation ship for real_estate field in Profile model and create new object i get this error =>

IntegrityError at /admin/users/profile/add/

NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.real_estate_id

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField()
    homes = models.ManyToManyField(Homes , related_name='home', blank=True)
    create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Profile(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('RE', 'مشاور املاک'),
        ('S', 'فروشنده'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    real_estate = models.OneToOneField(Business , related_name='business' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    type_of_user = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=CHOICES)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique = True, null = False, blank = False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have add full code to the question. so can't assume how you tried.

If you want to allow null, you can try this way:

```
real_estate = models.OneToOneField(Business , related_name='business' ,on_delete=models.SETNULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

and re-migrate, it should not fire you same error again